# Failed to start kernel modules

Tags: kernel, systemd

Whenever I boot ubuntu, it shows FAILED to start kernel modules. The system starts normally after it but on every restart it shows failed to start kernel modules. I saw on one post that doing the below command should not give errors but doing it gives the following:

Doing `journalctl | grep` modules gives the following:

```
May 20 13:59:37 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[287]: Inserted module 'lp'
May 20 13:59:37 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[287]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
May 20 13:59:37 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[287]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
May 20 13:59:37 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[287]: could not find module by name='off'
May 20 13:59:37 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[287]: Failed to insert 'off': No such file or directory
May 20 13:59:37 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[287]: could not find module by name='off'
May 20 13:59:37 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[287]: Failed to insert 'off': No such file or directory
May 20 13:59:38 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[366]: could not find module by name='off'
May 20 13:59:38 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[366]: Failed to insert 'off': No such file or directory
May 20 13:59:38 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[366]: could not find module by name='off'
May 20 13:59:38 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[366]: Failed to insert 'off': No such file or directory
May 20 13:59:38 Sarthak systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 20 13:59:38 Sarthak systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 20 13:59:38 Sarthak systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 20 13:59:39 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[568]: could not find module by name='off'
May 20 13:59:39 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[568]: Failed to insert 'off': No such file or directory
May 20 13:59:39 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[568]: could not find module by name='off'
May 20 13:59:39 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[568]: Failed to insert 'off': No such file or directory
May 20 13:59:39 Sarthak systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 20 13:59:39 Sarthak systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 20 13:59:39 Sarthak systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 20 13:59:40 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[589]: could not find module by name='off'
May 20 13:59:40 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[589]: Failed to insert 'off': No such file or directory
May 20 13:59:40 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[589]: could not find module by name='off'
May 20 13:59:40 Sarthak systemd-modules-load[589]: Failed to insert 'off': No such file or directory
May 20 13:59:40 Sarthak systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 20 13:59:40 Sarthak systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 20 13:59:40 Sarthak systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Also the result of `grep -v \# /etc/modules-load.d/*` is:

```
/etc/modules-load.d/cups-filters.conf:lp
/etc/modules-load.d/cups-filters.conf:ppdev
/etc/modules-load.d/cups-filters.conf:parport_pc
/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf:
/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf:nouveau


sarthak@Sarthak:~$ grep -v \# /usr/lib/modules-load.d/*.conf
grep: /usr/lib/modules-load.d/*.conf: No such file or directory
sarthak@Sarthak:~$ grep -v \# /run/modules-load.d/*.conf
grep: /run/modules-load.d/.conf: No such file or directory
sarthak@Sarthak:~$ grep -v \# /run/modules-load.d/*.conf
grep: /run/modules-load.d/*.conf: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me to solve it? I have no idea why it is happening.

Comment: Edited as per the commands^

Comment: `sarthak@Sarthak:~$ grep -v \# /run/modules-load.conf
grep: /run/modules-load.conf: No such file or directory
sarthak@Sarthak:~$ grep -v \# /run/modules-load.conf/*conf.
grep: /run/modules-load.conf/*conf.: No such file or directory`

Comment: `sarthak@Sarthak:~/Desktop/tensorflow-models/allcnn-c$ grep -v \# /run/modules-load.d/.conf
grep: /run/modules-load.d/.conf: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, did not find it.
Also, edited the post to contain more details.

Comment: **NOTE** when I posted my duplicate candidate, this question got closed on "unclear what you are asking" grounds but the problem seems clear to me.

Comment: Can you tell me how to solve it then please?